# How to see all flagged emails in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I used to see all my flagged emails at the top:

Before it was like this:
[image]

But now all the flagged emails disappeared from the top! Even the [advertised search for Flagged items](https://superuser.com/questions/830772/viewing-flagged-emails-in-outlook-hotmail) is no longer there.

I have hundreds of folders - each with thousands of emails and each folder has 1-10 flagged emails from last 20 years (yes, I have emails since 1997 in my MSN which got renamed to Hotmail which got renamed to Live mail which got renamed to Windows Live which got renamed to Windows mail which got renamed to Outlook mail).

There is a open bug report with 10000+ votes against Microsoft here: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/284136-outlook-com/suggestions/8159895-please-put-the-flagged-messages-on-top-like-you-di

but they have not replied!

What shall I do (**please don't tell me to use Gmail or download some software**)?

Answer (score 1):

1. In your picture, click the empty space in your search email.
2. A drop down menu shown, click flagged:

[image: flagged]

Taken from [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/833345/516846).

Comment: This does not work. There is no flagged button

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook Web, select the bottom left icon for Tasks, there you will find all flagged emails and tasks.
Another option is to open the Microsoft To-Do App, it has all flagged email.

Microsoft should include a Flagged folder in the Outlook folder list or an All Mail folder so users can filter for flagged mail.

Comment: The question is about Outlook.com rather than the Outlook web interface